# Is there a AWS CDK code available to enable WAF logging for Kinesis firehose delivery stream?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-waf

Anyone have Python CDK code to enable Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose delivery stream Logging in WAF? Any language CDK code is fine for my reference as I didn't find any proper syntax or examples to enable in official python CDK/api documentation nor in any blog.

Answer (score 1):

From the existing documentation (as of CDK version 1.101 and by extension Cloudformation) there seems to be no way of doing this out of the box.

But there is API call which can be utilized with boto3 for example: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/wafv2.html#WAFV2.Client.put_logging_configuration

What you need to have in order to invoke the call:

1. ResourceArn of the web ACL
2. List of Kinesis Data Firehose ARN(s) which should receive the logs

This means that you can try using Custom Resource and implement this behavior. Given you have created Firehose and web ACL in the stack previously, use this to create Custom Resource:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.custom_resources/README.html

```py
        crd_provider = custom_resources.Provider(
            self,
            "Custom resource provider",
            on_event_handler=on_event_handler,
            log_retention=aws_logs.RetentionDays.ONE_DAY
        )

        custom_resource = core.CustomResource(
            self,
            "WAF logging configurator",
            service_token=crd_provider.service_token,
            properties={
                "ResourceArn": waf_rule.attr_arn,
                "FirehoseARN": firehose.attr_arn
            }
        )
```

`on_event_handler` in this case is a lambda function which you need to implement.

It should be possible to simplify this further by using `AwsSdkCall`:

```py
on_event_handler = AwsSdkCall(
        action='PutLoggingConfiguration',
        service='waf',
        parameters={
            'ResourceArn': waf_rule.attr_arn,
            'LogDestinationConfigs': [
                firehose.attr_arn,
            ]
    )
```

This way you don't need to write your own lambda. But your use case might change and you might want to add some extra functionality to this logging configurator, so I'm showing both approaches.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this **exact** code, rather this is an excerpt of similar code written by me to solve similar problem of circumventing the gap in Cloudformation coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have python CDK example, but I had it working in Typescript using [CfnDeliverySteam](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_kinesisfirehose.CfnDeliveryStream.html) and [CfnLoggingConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnLoggingConfiguration.html). I would imagine you can find matching class in python CDK.